# How to safely remove std::thread in ATL DLL

Tags: c++, multithreading, atl, stdthread

I wrote an ATL DLL and I have problem with `std::thread` witch I used to run `asyn` method. I implemented method that performs operations asynchronously. The problem occurs when a client tries to remove the object class in which thread already done.

This is my code:

```
STDMETHODIMP CQRCodeGenerator::GenerateAsync(QRCodeTypeEnum QRCodeType, QRCodeFormatEnum QRCodeFormat, LONG QRCodePx, BSTR ImageFile)
{

if (ImageFile == nullptr) ImageFile = L"";

//stack to log file
OPFHelper::add_execute_method(this, L"CQRCodeGenerator::GenerateAsync",
    std::vector<std::wstring>{OPFHelper::ConvertToWSting((LONG)QRCodeType),
    OPFHelper::ConvertToWSting((LONG)QRCodeFormat), OPFHelper::ConvertToWSting((LONG)QRCodePx), ImageFile});

t = std::thread(&CQRCodeGenerator::run, this, QRCodeType, QRCodeFormat, QRCodePx, ImageFile);
return S_OK;
}

void CQRCodeGenerator::run(enum QRCodeTypeEnum QRCodeType, enum QRCodeFormatEnum QRCodeFormat, LONG QRCodePx, BSTR ImageFile)
{

 ......

Fire_OnGenerate(this,ImageFile, _pQRCode, _pInvoiceID, _pQRCodeMD5, _pKS,nullptr);
}
```

1. `std::thread` is declared in `.h` file
2. when I reception event and I try delete obj `QRCodeGenerator` I get error.

I know that this is a problem with the removal of the thread of memory, because I carried out synchronous function `Generate` which did not give error.

But I don't know how Can I delete this thread and detect when `Client` wants to delete obj. The second thing it can not understand why there is a problem with releasing memory when thread-assistant no longer works.

Comment: You can do something in the destructor of QRCodeGenerator right?

Comment: @TonyJ right , but whitch and what do? 
Whitch method is called when client  destroy obj ? HRESULT FinalConstruct() / void FinalRelease() ? and what ? t.join() ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with FinalConstruct()/FinalRelease(), but if you write a function to call t.join() if thread is not finished, then you can call it from FinalConstruct()/FinalRelease() and desctructor. Alternatively you can refactor CQRCodeGenerator to be just a wrapper class, so the thread is not coupled to it.

Comment: @TonyJ thanks for suggestion !

Answer (score 2):

Do you call `std::thread::join()` or `detach()` before destroying the thread? Otherwise the `std::thread` destructor is supposed to trigger `terminate()` and abort the program.

If something is owning the thread (as "*client tries to remove the object class in which thread already done*" suggests), the object might call `t.join()` in its destructor, for example.

Also note that you shouldn't destroy the object inside of `Fire_OnGenerate` - that is called in the scope of the running thread. So you would basically destroy a thread which is still running (it only can complete after `Fire_OnGenerate` returns back).

Comment: I'm talking about the situation when the event will return OnGenerate.
So where I must add t.join() in ATL class ? HRESULT FinalConstruct() ? void FinalRelease ? I don't know whitch method is called when client try destroy obj.